# I keep getting this error: object of type 'int' has no len(), in my code what should I change, to remove error

Tags: python

```
list_of_numbers = str(input("Please enter numbers(example 1 2 5 7):\n"))
list_of_numbers = list(list_of_numbers.split(" "))
list_of_integers = []
for e in list_of_numbers:
    e = int(e)
    list_of_integers.append(e)
    list_of_integers = list(list_of_integers)

for i in range(len(list_of_integers)): #I have also tried: for i in range(int(len(list_of_integers))): ##this is the line where the error pops up
    #object of type 'int' has no len()
```

SO I keep getting this error: #object of type 'int' has no len(). I don't know why when list_of_integers prints out it prints out like [1,2,3,4] which is what I want.

Comment: Please create a [mre] and share the full traceback

Answer (score 1):

The only error I got was that `list_of_integers` was not defined, so I added it and it works fine. However, I still don't know what the expected output is.

```
list_of_numbers = str(input("Please enter numbers(example 1 2 5 7):\n"))
list_of_numbers = list(list_of_numbers.split(" "))
list_of_integers = []
for e in list_of_numbers:
    e = int(e)
    list_of_integers.append(e)
    list_of_integers = list(list_of_integers)
print(list_of_integers)
```

Comment: when I add it I still get the same error

Comment: What do you mean by "when I add it"?

Comment: when I added list_of_integers = []

Comment: It works fine on my end. Is this part of a larger code? If so, post the rest of it, so I can take a look. But as it stands, i don't get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Robin Sage list_of_integers isn't defined. Probabaly you forgot to add that line to the question and you have initalized it to an integer